# Error when validating certificate path

Tags: java, security, ssl, x509

I am trying to validate a certificate path using Java security. I can't seem to get it to work however.

I have 4 Certificates: `CA`, `CA1`, `alice` and `bob`. `CA1` and `bob` are both signed by `CA`. `Alice` is signed by `CA1`.

The following test class has a number of tests. `testPath()` tries to ensure that the certificates actually have the relationship i think they have. This test succeeds.
Then next 3 tests attempts to create a certificate path for CA1, alice and bob, with CA as the trusted ca.
`bob` and `CA1` **succeeds**, and `alice` **fails**.

It SEEMS like my path builder fails when intermediate certificates are in play.

My test class

```
    package test.project;

import test.project.CertificateValidationException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.NoSuchProviderException;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.PublicKey;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.PKIXCertPathBuilderResult;
import java.security.cert.X509CRL;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.AfterClass;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.BeforeClass;
import org.junit.Test;


public class CertificateTest {
    static X509Certificate CA, CA1, alice, bob;
    static CertificateStore certStorage;

    public CertificateTest () {
    }

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException{
    Security.addProvider(new org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider());

    certStorage = new CertificateStore ();
    try(InputStream stream = AbstractCentralCertificateStorageTest.class.getResourceAsStream("/ca.crt")){
        CA = (X509Certificate)certStorage.certFactory.generateCertificate(stream);
    }
    try(InputStream stream = AbstractCentralCertificateStorageTest.class.getResourceAsStream("/ca-int1.crt")){
        CA1 = (X509Certificate)certStorage.certFactory.generateCertificate(stream);
    }
    try(InputStream stream = AbstractCentralCertificateStorageTest.class.getResourceAsStream("/alice.crt")){
        alice = (X509Certificate)certStorage.certFactory.generateCertificate(stream);
    }
    try(InputStream stream = AbstractCentralCertificateStorageTest.class.getResourceAsStream("/bob.crt")){
        bob = (X509Certificate)certStorage.certFactory.generateCertificate(stream);
    }
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownClass() {
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
    }

    /**
     * Test of validate method.
     */
    @Test
    public void testValidate_X509Certificate1() throws Exception {
    certStorage.setCAs(Arrays.asList(new X509Certificate[]{CA1}));
    certStorage.setTrustedCAs(Arrays.asList(new X509Certificate[]{CA}));
    certStorage.validate(alice);
    }

    @Test
    public void testValidate_X509Certificate1() throws Exception {
    certStorage.setCAs(Arrays.asList(new X509Certificate[]{CA1}));
    certStorage.setTrustedCAs(Arrays.asList(new X509Certificate[]{CA}));
    certStorage.validate(bob);
    }

    @Test
    public void testValidate_X509Certificate1() throws Exception {
    certStorage.setCAs(Arrays.asList(new X509Certificate[]{CA1}));
    certStorage.setTrustedCAs(Arrays.asList(new X509Certificate[]{CA}));
    certStorage.validate(CA1);
    }

    @Test
    public void testPath() throws Exception{
    alice.verify(CA1.getPublicKey());
    bob.verify(CA.getPublicKey());
    CA1.verify(CA.getPublicKey());

    alice.checkValidity();
    bob.checkValidity();
    CA.checkValidity();
    CA1.checkValidity();

    assertEquals(alice.getIssuerX500Principal(), CA1.getSubjectX500Principal());
    assertEquals(bob.getIssuerX500Principal(), CA.getSubjectX500Principal());
    assertEquals(CA1.getIssuerX500Principal(), CA.getSubjectX500Principal());
    }



}
```

The testPath test succeeds and the test for bob and CA1 succeeds, but the test for alice does not. It throws a CertPathBuilderException.

The method that throws the exception is this:

```
public PKIXCertPathBuilderResult buildPath(X509Certificate cert) throws CertificateValidationException, CertPathBuilderException {
X509Certificate cert;
X509Certificate[] intermediateCerts = new X509Certificate[0];
if(certChain != null && certChain.length>0){
    cert = certChain[0];
    if(certChain.length > 1){
    intermediateCerts = Arrays.copyOfRange(certChain, 1, certChain.length);
    }
}else{
    throw new CertificateValidationException(null, "Could not validate Certificate Chain. Chain was empty or Null");
}

logger.debug("Building path for "+cert+" with intermediates: "+Arrays.asList(intermediateCerts));

X509CertSelector selector = new X509CertSelector(); 

selector.setIssuer(cert.getIssuerX500Principal());
selector.setSerialNumber(cert.getSerialNumber());

    // Specify root CAs
    Set<TrustAnchor> trustAnchors = new HashSet<>();
    for (X509Certificate trustedRootCert : this.getTrustedCAs()) {
        trustAnchors.add(new TrustAnchor(trustedRootCert, null));
    }

    // Configure the PKIX certificate builder algorithm parameters
    PKIXBuilderParameters pkixParams;
try {
    pkixParams = new PKIXBuilderParameters(trustAnchors, selector);
} catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException ex) {
    throw new CertificateValidationException(cert, "Could not validate certificate. An invalid algorithm was speficied.", ex);
}
    pkixParams.setMaxPathLength(6);
    // Disable CRL checks. We have enough complexity thanks...
    pkixParams.setRevocationEnabled(false);

    // Specify a list certificates. Add both CA's trustedCAs and target
    CertStore intermediateCertStore;
try {
    Set<X509Certificate> certificates = new HashSet<>();
    certificates.addAll(this.getTrustedCAs());      //Gets the trustedCAs set in the test (CA)
    certificates.addAll(this.getCAs());         //Gets the CAs set in the test (CA1)
    certificates.add(cert);  //Sets the certificate target

    intermediateCertStore = CertStore.getInstance("Collection", new CollectionCertStoreParameters(certificates));

} catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException | NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
    throw new CertificateValidationException(cert, "Could not validate certificate. Exception caught when creating intermediate cert store", ex);
} 
    pkixParams.addCertStore(intermediateCertStore);


    // Build and verify the certification chain
    CertPathBuilder builder;
try {
    builder = CertPathBuilder.getInstance("PKIX");
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
    throw new CertificateValidationException(cert, "Could not validate certificate. Exception caught when creating CertPathBuilder", ex);
}
//Log a lot of stuff    
for(TrustAnchor anchor : pkixParams.getTrustAnchors()){
    logger.debug("trustedCA: "+anchor.getTrustedCert());
}
for(CertStore store : pkixParams.getCertStores()){
    try {
    for(Certificate c : store.getCertificates(null)){
        logger.debug("CA: store: "+store.getType()+"["+store.getProvider().getName()+"]: "+c);
    }
    } catch (CertStoreException ex) {
    logger.debug("Could not retrieve cert");
    }
}

    PKIXCertPathBuilderResult result;
try {
    result = (PKIXCertPathBuilderResult) builder.build(pkixParams);
} catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException ex) {
    throw new CertificateValidationException(cert, "Could not validate certificate. Exception caught when building Certificate path", ex);
} 
return result;
}
```

The methods `getTrustedCAs` and `getCAs` return Trusted Certificate Authorities and Certificate authorities. The logs tell me that the certificate "CA" is returned by getTrustedCAs() and "CA1" is returned by getCAs().

The `testPath` test shows that alice is signed by CA1(Intermediate), bob is signed by CA(Trusted CA) and that CA1 is signed by CA.

I can see in the log that all certificates are loaded into the intermediateCertstore, both in the log and through my debugger.

Can someone tell me what i'm doing wrong? Why does the method work on bob and CA1, which are directly signed by CA, but not on alice, which is signed by CA1? Am i misunderstanding something about certificates, or do i have code problems?

None of the certificates are revoked, or outside the validity periods.

Certificates printed to string:

```
23:48:14.949 [main] DEBUG c.P.l.u.AbstractCentralCertificateStorage - CA: store: Collection[SUN]:   [0]         Version: 3
         SerialNumber: -87661101532789169401713647165930791168
             IssuerDN: CN=CAROOT
           Start Date: Tue Jul 14 23:48:14 CEST 2015
           Final Date: Sun Jul 19 23:48:14 CEST 2015
            SubjectDN: CN=CAROOT
           Public Key: RSA Public Key
            modulus: 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
    public exponent: 10001

  Signature Algorithm: SHA1WITHRSA
            Signature: a63b11692c4115f316619dbc703104c0cd14ff7a
                       011fdc6822cf9f46bd951a58d6d9bba321422141
                       2c7fae53828f8e65d2f27e4ecd5392b91df18bdb
                       e78eea91b7d1e18e3b221b4c5e0d6d8cc8bfd0d9
                       b86f42f12ce64b0ea19752aff813cbaec267f522
                       81298e823b05cc76913a03967b735c03517ee4bd
                       d44a2de561a1a9fa4b120b08fa7fbdc112f88d20
                       b3dffbae75155d3fcc8427da7ffdd8fca4d6329c
                       163d15c0a23673634a54ad9ee131445e6f543e57
                       194eb6d0b2cb40cdd4248ddaa18d1c78105f6704
                       4202db4e2882daeed7376210e3a9638d0a6f01b5
                       65e0e87c853600907c1a6451f19251d91b3825dd
                       7d07ce0350a9606eebcccf950caefde7
       Extensions: 
                       critical(false) 2.5.29.14 value = DER Octet String[20] 

                       critical(false) 2.5.29.35 value = Sequence
    Tagged [0] IMPLICIT 
        DER Octet String[20] 

                       critical(false) KeyUsage: 0x6
                       critical(false) 2.5.29.37 value = Sequence
    ObjectIdentifier(2.5.29.37.0)

                       critical(false) 2.5.29.17 value = Sequence
    Tagged [6] IMPLICIT 
        DER Octet String[19] 

                       critical(false) 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.1 value = Sequence
    Sequence
        ObjectIdentifier(1.3.6.1.5.5.7.48.2)
        Tagged [6] IMPLICIT 
            DER Octet String[14] 
    Sequence
        ObjectIdentifier(1.3.6.1.5.5.7.48.1)
        Tagged [6] IMPLICIT 
            DER Octet String[16] 

                       critical(false) 2.5.29.31 value = Sequence
    Sequence
        Tagged [0]
            Tagged [0]
                Tagged [6] IMPLICIT 
                    DER Octet String[15] 


23:48:14.952 [main] DEBUG c.P.l.u.AbstractCentralCertificateStorage - CA: store: Collection[SUN]:   [0]         Version: 3
         SerialNumber: 126038779198800081330846530986414066668
             IssuerDN: CN=CAROOT
           Start Date: Tue Jul 14 23:48:14 CEST 2015
           Final Date: Sun Jul 19 23:48:14 CEST 2015
            SubjectDN: CN=INTERMEDIATE
           Public Key: RSA Public Key
            modulus: 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
    public exponent: 10001

  Signature Algorithm: SHA1WITHRSA
            Signature: 2acefadb8d9669e305723b4f6e0c2da00cae588d
                       a8a390c2bd9abaa830f8f68f07ae6df06d1a9b2a
                       9c7d342e80e114c9ff7aa829beab84c35fdf9cc9
                       cb6b37ce66824e87bc4f42289a9e52ac13cb3d57
                       02c3fc7f0b86138cc3a844bb80235ea1091e8354
                       de7f5f1b1581aacb5527f331a7bc706d2b1e6d22
                       74a428eed280905b86e631a5bc9546433df90033
                       e6e4a66e367fe50f249aa32529d7b7343d2c9a42
                       ed6109356ae6241812145ef4a83c537038a00ecb
                       68a86fda20bcbb072801dbb4d8e547a356948a65
                       a417b87a64ccd244eac23cc0ef9dd24ac071d9e1
                       40750eda7be97728c293c36cbd692c44415fec15
                       fa658d80d231602cb6762e509aade70a
       Extensions: 
                       critical(false) 2.5.29.14 value = DER Octet String[20] 

                       critical(false) 2.5.29.35 value = Sequence
    Tagged [0] IMPLICIT 
        DER Octet String[20] 

                       critical(false) KeyUsage: 0x6
                       critical(false) 2.5.29.37 value = Sequence
    ObjectIdentifier(2.5.29.37.0)

                       critical(false) 2.5.29.17 value = Sequence
    Tagged [6] IMPLICIT 
        DER Octet String[19] 

                       critical(false) 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.1 value = Sequence
    Sequence
        ObjectIdentifier(1.3.6.1.5.5.7.48.2)
        Tagged [6] IMPLICIT 
            DER Octet String[14] 
    Sequence
        ObjectIdentifier(1.3.6.1.5.5.7.48.1)
        Tagged [6] IMPLICIT 
            DER Octet String[16] 

                       critical(false) 2.5.29.31 value = Sequence
    Sequence
        Tagged [0]
            Tagged [0]
                Tagged [6] IMPLICIT 
                    DER Octet String[15] 


23:48:14.954 [main] DEBUG c.P.l.u.AbstractCentralCertificateStorage - CA: store: Collection[SUN]:   [0]         Version: 3
         SerialNumber: -144831244968902948917803188139978579108
             IssuerDN: CN=INTERMEDIATE
           Start Date: Tue Jul 14 23:48:14 CEST 2015
           Final Date: Sun Jul 19 23:48:14 CEST 2015
            SubjectDN: DC=DC2,DC=DC1,OU=OU2,OU=OU1,CN=Alice
           Public Key: RSA Public Key
            modulus: 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
    public exponent: 10001

  Signature Algorithm: SHA1WITHRSA
            Signature: 3ddb0118a9651c9b18aab7ef75abe307ac02b589
                       66b10eaf36c9b565185cca3e4f04d81b7bb97a27
                       1d644ce3f0756c76881598e55f14ddfeaa5843c9
                       4268814b067e422bca234efc314b51b1620bb7cd
                       a7cc1dd3b6f6fb15f4a81d175e9f2a07df6fa698
                       96817780bd15d7abf086fb86962da9022a1f489f
                       a70cfc68acda2c3afb19a270663df282cfd58efb
                       15dfc3eb00ce3933488d699717248f14aaba7058
                       c11630f67134d2c740e78cea2f67a75141cf3690
                       109bd9ea112192c2ec35836cd5d6bc1f2484abd0
                       e1597bc8540be4bdb95935b2020b72c028a0893b
                       525e0059749f7cbb0141b09740778d5dbdcbcd69
                       f66c353e70c1419602e98b3be2a30a82
       Extensions: 
                       critical(false) 2.5.29.14 value = DER Octet String[20] 

                       critical(false) 2.5.29.35 value = Sequence
    Tagged [0] IMPLICIT 
        DER Octet String[20] 

                       critical(false) KeyUsage: 0xb0
                       critical(false) 2.5.29.32 value = Sequence
    Sequence
        ObjectIdentifier(2.5.29.32.0)

                       critical(false) 1.3.6.1.5.5.7.1.1 value = Sequence
    Sequence
        ObjectIdentifier(1.3.6.1.5.5.7.48.2)
        Tagged [6] IMPLICIT 
            DER Octet String[14] 
    Sequence
        ObjectIdentifier(1.3.6.1.5.5.7.48.1)
        Tagged [6] IMPLICIT 
            DER Octet String[16] 

                       critical(false) 2.5.29.31 value = Sequence
    Sequence
        Tagged [0]
            Tagged [0]
                Tagged [6] IMPLICIT 
                    DER Octet String[15]
```

Comment: You might have to set issuer as encoded : cert.getIssuerX500Principal().getEncoded()

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I just tried, and it had no effect unfortunately.

Comment: Can you share the certificates for reproducing the issue?

Comment: I added a toString of the certs. Is that enough?

Comment: The `toString` outputs give more information for analysis but are not enough for reproducing the problem.

Comment: @MartinNielsen did you resolve this problem ,and if yes how ? I have the exact issue with an intermediate certificate and it's really frustrating.

Comment: Oh man this is way beyond what my terrible memory can do. I am a bit stressed this week, so i can't dig too much into it now i'm afraid. If i remember correctly i did fix it, i just don't remember how. If you want to check out the tests for the certs is here: https://github.com/mnybon/POLIS/blob/master/certificatestorage-file/src/test/java/com/POLIS/licensing/userhandling/CFCS/CentralFileCertificateStorageTest.java while the actual method resides here https://github.com/mnybon/POLIS/blob/master/subject-core/src/main/java/com/POLIS/licensing/userhandling/AbstractCentralCertificateStorage.java

Comment: Was anyone able to solve this issue, I am stuck at it from sometime ..... Do you remember how you have solved this by any chance @MartinNielsen